# String1 - result1 - string2 - result2

Tags: mysql

So i need to find out a query that might print a sentence like this example:

> "The most expensive item is Apple and the cheapest item is LG"

```
Example table: 
+---------+-------+---------+
|  item   | price | inStock |
+---------+-------+---------+
| Samsung |    55 |      40 |
| Apple   |    80 |      45 |
| LG      |    45 |      25 |
+---------+-------+---------+
```

This is what I have so far, but my print out is giving me this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('The most expensive item is ', item SEPARATOR ' and the
cheapest item is ') 
FROM table_name 
WHERE price=(SELECT MAX(price) FROM table_name) OR price=(SELECT MIN(price) FROM table_name) 
GROUP BY 'all';
```

> "The most expensive item is Apple and the cheapest item is, The most
>   expensive item is  LG and the cheapest item is"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('The most expensive item is ',
    (SELECT item
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) from yourTable)),
    ' and the cheapest item is ',
    (SELECT item
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE price = (SELECT MIN(price) from yourTable)))
```

Comment: Great! This worked exactly like I needed it! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('The most expensive item is ', 
              GROUP_CONCAT(item ORDER BY price DESC 
                           SEPARATOR ' and the cheapest item is ') )
FROM table_name 
WHERE price=(SELECT MAX(price) FROM table_name) OR 
      price=(SELECT MIN(price) FROM table_name)
```

This query will of course not work in case of ties.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa97a1/3)